# Регулярное выражение в sql запросе

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

В таблице в поле category записана строка:

```
{"data":[{"key":20517,"children":[{"key":20764,"children":[{"key":20766,"children":[{"key":20770},{"key":22948},{"key":23014}]}]}]}]}
```

Я знаю что это json. Но мне нужно найти SQL-запросом среди множество подобных строк, только ту строку где **после последнего вхождения children** есть, например, подстрока - 22948 
Подскажите , пожалуйста, как это сделать ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+json

Comment: @Visman Не поможет. Задачу невозможно решить в рамках одного запроса, обрабатывая данные как JSON. Внешне данные выглядят как вложенные без ограничения по уровню вложенности - а у MySQL проблемы с рекурсивными запросами. Я понимаю, что можно сделать псевдотаблицу на триллион - но это кривой костыль, формально не меняющий положения дел.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE INSTR(category, '"children"')
  AND INSTR(SUBSTRING_INDEX(category, '"children"', -1), '22948')
```

Регулярка тут не нужна.